# basename() expects parameter 1 to be string array given codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

This is my code, I want to add images dynamically in database. How can I do that?

This is my controller

```
if($this->input->post('title'))
             {

                $values['prootherinfo']=$this->AdminModel->select_table('pro_otherinfo');
                foreach($values['prootherinfo']->result() as $r)  
                $image=$r->othr_info_image;
                $path=FCPATH."assets/images/".$image;
                unlink($path);
                $target_dir = FCPATH."assets/images/";
                $arrfile = pos($_FILES);
                $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);



                  $title = $this->input->post('title', true);
                  $desc = $this->input->post('desc', true);
                  $proid = $this->input->post('pro_id', true);      


                foreach ($title as $i => $a) { // need index to match other properties
                   foreach ($desc as $dd => $d)

                    $keyt = array(
                        'othr_info_image'=>$_FILES["userfile"]["name"],
                        'title' => $a,
                        'description' => $d,
                        'pro_id' => $proid

                    );
                    //print_r($keyt);

                    if (!$this->db->insert('pro_otherinfo', $keyt)) {
                        // quit if insert fails - adjust accordingly
                        print_r($keyt);
                        die('Failed insert');
                     }    
                 }
             }
```

this is my view

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]">
```

Comment: Please can you remove the repeated text at the top, ask an actual question and review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Debug what is `basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]` and you'll see what to change.

Answer (score 0):

The error message in your title states exactly where your error is. You can actually see what is in the global $_FILES array by simply printing it:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

It will look like this:

```
Array (
    [userfile] => Array (
        [name] => Array (
                [0] => file.txt
            )
        [type] => ...
    )

)
```

As you can see the *name* index is an array and not a string. You have to choose which of these files you want to use (or use all).

That means in your example you could use

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"][0]);
```

Of course you have to check if every index is set properly.